# How can I get my LND node to make connections over Tor, IPv4, and IPv6?

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, tor

I followed this guide (https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/docs/configuring_tor.md) to setup Tor on my LND node, but this forced all my traffic through Tor, and I was no longer reachable over Clearnet. I've looked through some issues on the LND github page, and it seems there is a way to have my node listen over Tor, IPv4, and IPv6, but I'm not sure how to set it up that way. Also, they mentioned there are risks to doing this, what are those risks? I don't mind if people can correlate my IP address to my onion address (I'm just running servers in the cloud anyway). I just want to be able to connect and route payments with Tor nodes and clearnet nodes. How can I get my LND node to make connections over Tor, IPv4, and IPv6? What configuration options must I set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [guide](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/docs/configuring_tor.md) you linked is a good start.

The next step is to broadcast these IPs using the `externalip` flag in the `lnd.conf` file. A sample `lnd.conf` file that enables connections (using default port 9735) via Tor, IPv4, and IPv6 should include the following:

(replace the 3 fake addresses with your own):

```
tor.active=1
tor.v3=1
tor.privatekeypath=~/.lnd/v3_onion_private_key
externalip=32.260.201.72
externalip=2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
externalip=rvaslfkj2blahblahbalhdfsfjdflxcmnvxcvxvkfdsxcvxcvxcv.onion
```

Comment: How do you get the onion externalip? do you first run it with tor.active and check the logs for the address? Stop it and add it back to the config? Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

the risk is, Port 8333 is open and stays open.
Its like an open Backdoor.
A Bad gguy could just check all nodes wich he can see on the earn.com Page ( and there are ALL Nodes listed) how secure their Network is.
I say, secure your home network with a strong password, do not allow guest entry and if you dont use your home network simply switch it of, dont set Folder or Files free in your network, especially sensitive ones.
And dont backup your Wallet on the same PC as you run your node from, never ever.

Comment: thanks but this does not answer my question. i'm running my LND node on a cloud server, not my home network. i will edit the question so its more clear